# Leading blank space converting date to string in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have this formula in Crystal:

```
totext({eCSRStat.ContactOriginatedStamp},"M/d/yyyy")
```

The date is coming out formatted like 8/ 8/2014, with an extra space before the day. I imagine this has to be a bug. I am using Crystal Reports 2008 version 12.4.0.966. Any way to work around this blank space before the day?

Answer (score 2):

Should have thought of this, pretty easy fix:

```
replace(totext({eCSRStat.ContactOriginatedStamp},"M/d/yyyy")," ", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `"M/dd/yyyy"` should replace the space you get with a leading 0 instead.